# Display UIAlertView before segue to next view

Tags: xamarin.ios, ios6

I have a UITableView in a ViewController that performs a segue to a detail view in another ViewController. Part of the detail view is populated from an async webservice, which could take some time.
 I would like my UIAlertView to display when the tableView receives the RowSelected event and hide after the webservice call is complete.

The sequence as it is now:
1. Populate UITableView (works fine)
2. Receive RowSelected event (works fine)
3. Show UIAlertView with msg "Loading" (shows too late)
4. Perform segue to detail view (works fine)
5. Load values from global variables into textfields.  (works fine)
6. Perform async webservice to get addition detail info (works fine)
7. Hide UIAlertView (works fine)

The problem is that the UIAlertView only shows up between step 4 and 5.

Source for RowSelected Event:

```
public override void RowSelected (UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
        {
            ActivityThread.Start ("Loading Quote list"); //shows UIAlertView
            var quoteList = service.GetQuoteList(Globals.UserName,Globals.Password,Globals.CompanyId,Globals.SelectedCustomer.CustomerId);      
            Globals.QuoteSelected = quoteList[indexPath.Row];
            ViewQuote viewQuote = new ViewQuote(QuoteViewController.handle);
            viewQuote.PerformSegue("quoteSegue",this);          
            tableView.DeselectRow (indexPath, true);
        }
```

Source for detail view Load:

```
    public override void ViewDidLoad ()
    {
        base.ViewDidLoad ();
        handle = Handle;

        //ActivityThread.Start("Retrieving Quote Data"); //shows UIAlertView too late
        LoadGlobalVariables();
        //hook up async websvc call
        service.GetQuoteLineListCompleted += new GetQuoteLineListCompletedEventHandler(OnGetQuoteLineListCompleted);  
        service.GetQuoteLineListAsync(Globals.UserName,Globals.Password,Globals.CompanyId,Globals.SelectedCustomer.CustomerId,Globals.QuoteSelected.DocumentHeaderId);

    }
```

Source for asyncCompleted event:

```
void OnGetQuoteLineListCompleted (object sender, GetQuoteLineListCompletedEventArgs args)
        {               
            var QuoteLineList = args.Result;

            QuoteItemTableView.Source = new QuoteItemTableSource(LoadLineData (QuoteLineList.ToList ()));

            ActivityThread.Stop (); //hide UIAlertview
        }
```

Source for ActivityThread:

```
public static class ActivityThread
    {
        private static Thread AcThread { get; set; }

        private static UILoadingView _loadView
        { get; set;}

        public static void Start(string title)
        {
            AcThread = new Thread(NewThreadMethod as ThreadStart);
            _loadView = new UILoadingView("", title);                   
            AcThread.Start();
            _loadView.BeginInvokeOnMainThread (delegate{_loadView.Show();});
        }

        public static void Stop()
        {
            AcThread.Abort();
            _loadView.BeginInvokeOnMainThread (delegate{_loadView.Hide ();});
        }

        [Export("NewThreadMethod")]
        static void NewThreadMethod()       
        {       
            using(var pool = new NSAutoreleasePool()) {}        
        }


    }
```

How do I get the UIAlertView to go to the top of the execution stack?

Comment: Can you post your code for `ActivityThread`?

Answer (score 1):

You code is a bit hard to follow (just trying to help). I would almost recommend getting rid of that `ActivityThread` class entirely, it's usefulness isn't that apparent to me--might be easier to just use your `loadingView` class directly where you need it. That's all besides the point though.

Have you tried not using `BeginInvokeOnMainThread` for showing the loading view in some cases?

You can check if it's already on the main thread by doing something like:

`if (NSThread.CurrentThread.IsMainThread)`

That's off the top of my head, but should be close.  You could also require a boolean flag indicating if it should call `BeginInvoke` or not.